# Template helper to wait till user account gets checked

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code causes the `headerLabel` on the page to flicker first to "Please login" then to "Select item from menu" in the case of an existing valid account. How can it be fixed so that it shows no "Please login" since their is a user logged in already? Thanks

**edit**

As suggested in Ramil's answer. the modified code below still does not work and I still get the flicker of "Please login".

```
    Template.header.helpers({
      headerLabel: () => {
        const user = Meteor.user();
        if (user) {
          return user.profile.header || Session.get('header') || 'Select item from menu';
        } else {
          return 'Please login';
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<template name="header">
  <header>
    <h1 class="main-menu">
          <button class="mainMenu" type="button">&#9776;</button>
        </h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <p class="header">
      {{headerLabel}}
    </p>
    {{else}}
    <p class="header">
      Please login
    </p>
    {{/if}}
    <h1>
          <button class="subMenu" type="button">&#8942;</button>
        </h1>
  </header>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is builtin [`{{currentUser}}`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#currentUser) helper in `accounts` package.

You can use it to check whether the user is logged in.

```html
<template name="header">
  <header>

  {{#if currentUser}}
    <p>
      Select item from menu
    </p>
  {{else}}
    <p>
      Please login
    </p>
  {{/if}}

  </header>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry, That did not work, I still get the same problem.

Comment: @FredJ. Is there any chance you're missing a package? {{#if currentUser}} should work like a charm (without your helper, exactly like how Ramil wrote)

Comment: @Luna I added some extra code I had in case that is causing the problem.

Comment: @FredJ. I think thats the case as currentUser works out of the box